# Get the input from Prompt and use it to change a field inside a javascript file, Yeoman

Tags: javascript, node.js, yeoman, yeoman-generator

### I'm doing a generator using Yeoman

I know it must be very simple, but I start using yeoman very recently and I'm not very familiar with it.

I want to get the user's input and use it to change a class name or variable

---

I ask the user what is the name of the class

```
this.controllerName = await this.prompt({
        type: 'input',
        name: 'controllerName',
        message: `What's the name of the controller?`
      })
```

I know how to change the file's name

```
this.destinationPath(`${this.controllerName.controllerName}Controller.js`)
```

But I don't know how to change a field inside the file. Example:

My template class

```
class TemplateController {
  createTemplate (req, res) {
    console.log('GET request')
    res.json('URL WORKING!')
  }
```

I'd like to change the class/method name for what the user answered in the prompt

```
class UserController {
  createUser (req, res) {
    console.log('GET request')
    res.json('URL WORKING!')
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add placeholders to your base file ( yeoman uses EJS template engine ):

_controller.js

```
class <%= name %>Controller {
  create<%= name %> (req, res) {
    console.log('GET request')
    res.json('URL WORKING!')
  }
}
```

Pass *user input* as `name` to your template:

index.js

```
...
writing() {
  this.fs.copyTpl(
    this.templatePath('_controller.js'),
    this.destinationPath(`${this.controllerName.controllerName}Controller.js`),
    {
      name: this.controllerName.controllerName
    }
  )
}
...
```

Comment: This was my first question here, I didn't expect an answer so soon, thanks. Btw it worked